# How do I incorporate Skulpt into my Meteor.js webapp?

Tags: python, meteor

Atmosphere.js lacks a Skulpt package, so I'm unsure how to proceed. If Meteor doesn't support Skulpt, is there a way to let users type and run Python code on my Meteor app (and if so, can you provide a small example of how to implement it)?

I'm currently using the Meteor-Blaze stack.

I originally tried using trinket.io. Then I learned of the same-origin policy (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy), which prevents me from grabbing what users type from the trinket or inserting my own content.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Skulpt is in Javascript, there is no reason why you shouldn't be able to use it in your Meteor app. There is an npm package, so you should be able to do

```
npm install skulpt
```

and

```
import skulpt from 'skulpt'
```

in your code where you want to use it.

I haven't tried this, I just found the npm package, which is a good indication for you.

Comment: that worked, thank you! I'm new to Meteor - is it true that npm packages, in general, are Meteor-compatible?

Comment: Yes, the original packaging system still exists, and as npm was so popular it made sense to support both